# multiple fonts in one line of a QListWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I need to include text and greek symbols (for simple mathematical equations) in the different options proposed by a QListWidget in a '.ui' file (I use to work with Qt Designer and I like python if it matters). I want the options to appear like this:

```
theta = phi^2 (toto et al.)
theta = phi^2.5 (tata et al.)
theta = 1-log(phi/2) (mister brown et al.)
...
```

with 'theta' and 'phi' replaced by their symbol. Strangely, this turns out to be not so simple...

How to define several fonts in one line of a QListWidget ? Same question with Qt Designer.

Comment: pyqt4 or pyqt5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is to use HTML to generate the symbols of the equation, for example the following lines:

```
&theta;  = &phi;<sup>2</sup> (toto et al.)
&theta;  = &phi;<sup>2.5</sup> (tata et al.)
&theta;  = 1-log(&phi;/2) (mister brown et al.)
```

generate the following output:

θ  = φ<sup>2</sup> (toto et al.)
θ  = φ<sup>2.5</sup> (tata et al.)
θ  = 1-log(φ/2) (mister brown et al.)

but QListWidget does not recognize this format, a solution for this is to create a delegate to recognize that format:

[image]

```
class HTMLDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        self.initStyleOption(option,index)
        painter.save()
        doc = QtGui.QTextDocument()
        doc.setHtml(option.text)
        option.text = ""
        option.widget.style().drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, option, painter)

        painter.translate(option.rect.left(), option.rect.top())
        clip = QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, option.rect.width(), option.rect.height())
        doc.drawContents(painter, clip)
        painter.restore()

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        self.initStyleOption(option,index)
        doc = QtGui.QTextDocument()
        doc.setHtml(option.text)
        doc.setTextWidth(option.rect.width())
        return QtCore.QSize(doc.idealWidth(), doc.size().height())
```

then we add him as a delegate with the following lines:

```
qlistwidget.setItemDelegate(HTMLDelegate())
```

Output:

[image]

The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/c524a51e734de0377b2746715b1f721c)

Comment: I just realized a strange bug with this implementation: when selecting one of the lines (it seems to be the longest line except if it is also the last line, to be verified), 2 lines appear selected. Not sure I'm clear... To illustrate, insert a line of 50 '#' in this list (not at the end) and try to select it in the GUI.

Comment: also a change of line with 'qlistwidget.setCurrentRow(2)' doesn't work anymore